# Facebook App Invite iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook

I m implementing Facebook app invite functionality in my app.
If app is not installed, "fetchDeferredAppLink" method always return nil url without any error.

Steps to reproduce bug:

1. Install app from app store
2. Send app invite with deep link data
3. Now uninstall the app
4. Open facebook application and tap on app invite notification
5. It will redirect to app store
6. Do not install app from app store, run it using xcode
7. Check for [FBSDKAppLinkUtility fetchDeferredAppLink:^(NSURL url, NSError error) method in app delegate
8. It will return nil url and error.
9. Above test case is working fine in iOS 9 (not in iOS 10)

Thanks